# Why can't I run a CLion project

Tags: c, clion

I'm very new to CLion and to proggraming and don't know a lot of the expressions so please be gentle.

I have downloaded CLion for Windows. I opened a new project and I can't run it.

The versioni is 2019.1.
The (default) CMakeLIsts is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(untitled4 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(untitled4 main.c)
```

Maybe I have a configuration problem (which as I said before don't understand what it means). Thanks.

Comment: What are you doing to try to run your program?  What happens when you do?

Comment: And have you actually *written* a program?  Your project is configured to expect the program's source code to be in a file named `main.c`, so what's there?

Comment: When I open a new project, a default 'Hello World' project is created and ready to be run. There's the 'run' botton (green triangle) which is disabled for pressing.

Comment: The `main.c` project is a simple default "Hello World" project. i.e.
`#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try shift+f10 (or whatever combination you see when you hover your mouse on the button although i guess it is the same in 2019.1 just as 2018.3), just created a project from scratch, bumped into the same problem(run button not available for pressing) however shift+f10 happened to solve it.

edit: after running the code for first time the button is now available.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CLion's UI, but this suggests that the issue is that you must compile the program before you can run it (which is in no way unique to CLion) and that it does not do that automatically for you, at least the first time, which is very important to know.